# SQL - Cross tab. Sum of a field instead of count rows in columns

Tags: sql, ssms, crosstab

Currently trying to create a query that will give me sales made by an agent by day for the whole year. I've managed to get the total column to work, but the daily sales don't, from looking at the raw data it seems that rather than summing the total sales made by day for a particular agent it is instead counting all rows with that agent listed and outputting that instead.
Code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(20), [ENTRY_DATE], 106)) 
                  FROM [Sales_Data] with (NoLock) 
                where([ENTRY_DATE] between '01-Jan-2017' and '01-Jul-2017'


                Group By [ENTRY_DATE]
                order by [ENTRY_DATE]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 

' SELECT 
  [Advisor_Name]                                                                AS    [Advisor_Name]
 ,[Line_Managers_Name]                                                          AS    [Line_Managers_Name]
 ,[SALE_TYPE]
 ,[Total]
 ,'+ @cols +'

    From  (
            Select 
                    sum([SALES]) 
                                over(partition by [Advisor_Name], [Line_Managers_Name], [SALE_TYPE]) 
                                      [Total]
                                ,    [ENTRY_DATE]
                                ,    [Advisor_Name]
                                ,     [Line_Managers_Name]
                                ,    [SALE_TYPE]


            From [Sales_Data] a with (NoLock)        



        )     x

    pivot 

    (
                                      Count([ENTRY_DATE])
                                      for [ENTRY_DATE] in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p 


Order by    [Advisor_Name],     [Line_Managers_Name],     [CHANNEL]          

'

execute(@query)
```

If I couldn't change the query I had planned on instead altering the source data to give me line by line sale info rather than aggregating into a sum, unfortunately some of the rows might have a customer with a -1 sale to indicate a refund and I don't know how to accommodate for these, I have tried select distinct, select from (select distinct.....) having count(*) = 1, but nothing seems to want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also amended our dynamically generated SQL to generate new Output.

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colsForPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(20), [ENTRY_DATE], 106)) + ',0)'
                  FROM [Sales_Data] with (NoLock) 
                where([ENTRY_DATE] between '01-Jan-2017' and '01-Jul-2017')
                Group By [ENTRY_DATE]
                order by [ENTRY_DATE]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

select @colsForPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(20), [ENTRY_DATE], 106))
              FROM [Sales_Data] with (NoLock) 
            where([ENTRY_DATE] between '01-Jan-2017' and '01-Jul-2017')
            Group By [ENTRY_DATE]
            order by [ENTRY_DATE]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')

set @query = 

'SELECT 

[Advisor_Name], [Line_Managers_Name], [SALE_TYPE], ISNULL(TotalSales,0), '
+ @cols + ' 

    From  (
            Select distinct
                    sum([SALES]) 
                                over(partition by [Advisor_Name], [Line_Managers_Name], [SALE_TYPE],    [ENTRY_DATE]) 
                                      [Total]
                                ,    [ENTRY_DATE]
                                ,    [Advisor_Name]
                                ,     [Line_Managers_Name]
                                ,    [SALE_TYPE],
sum([SALES]) 
over(partition by [Advisor_Name], [Line_Managers_Name], [SALE_TYPE]) as TotalSales


            From [Sales_Data] a with (NoLock)        



        )     x

    pivot 

    (
                                      sum([Total]) 
                                      for [ENTRY_DATE] in (' + @colsForPivot + ')
    ) p 


Order by    [Advisor_Name],     [Line_Managers_Name]      

'

print(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great!
One slight error, that if you could fix would go a long way towards naming a child after you, is there any way of replacing the NULL entries in the date columns with a 0 instead?

The aim is to be able to copy it straight into excel, but with the amount of entries I have (approx. 8000 agents over 6 months) trying to find and replace in excel nearly crashes my system.

Comment: Sure thing. Any column you want to replace null, just do this. ISNULL(columnName, 0). If the column ia NULL them retun 0 otherwise retun the value in the column.

Comment: Please namd the child "Dave"!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, I had to try and simulate your data but it looks like I'm getting good results.

```
 SELECT 
 *
    From  (
Select distinct
sum([Total]) 
over(partition by [Advisor_Name], [Line_Managers_Name], [SALE_TYPE],    [ENTRY_DATE]) as Total
,    [ENTRY_DATE]
,    [Advisor_Name]
,     [Line_Managers_Name]
,    [SALE_TYPE],
sum([Total]) 
over(partition by [Advisor_Name], [Line_Managers_Name], [SALE_TYPE]) as TotalSales

            From [Sales_Data] a with (NoLock)        

        )     x
    pivot 
    (
          Sum(Total)
          for [ENTRY_DATE] in ([01 Jan 2017],[02 Jan 2017],[03 Jan 2017])
    ) p 


Order by    [Advisor_Name],     [Line_Managers_Name]
```